# Regulations with LaTeX

Tags: templates

I need to create a sort of "regulation" for an upcoming election on my community. I tried searching for templates, but the closer I got was [this one](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/contract), which does not suit my needs. I need something that contains "articles and sections", in the same style, say, of a Constitution. Does there exist something like this?

As an example, I would like something that could serve as a TeX template for the  (non-TeX) format of the contents of [this link](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Constituicao/Constituicao.htm).

Comment: This question is very broad, in my point of view.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you tell me how I could make it more specific?

Comment: A screen shot of something similar or a photograph of an existing paper would help.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, I can't find an example of something like that being done with TeX. But I want something that can represent the following format, for example (sorry, it is in Portuguese, but I think it may still be illustrative):

http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Constituicao/Constituicao.htm

Comment: Thanks, that's a starter. The language is not important to understand the look of that (web)document (and we have a very famous TeX user from Brazil who could help ;-)) As far as I can see, most of the contents are enumerations in Roman numbers

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for helping. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Hi @Aloizio! Great to see a fellow Brazilian around! Take a look at the [`br-lex` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/br-lex) available on CTAN, courtesy of my good friend Youssef Cherem. `:)` It is a class written for the sole purpose of writing Brazilian legal texts. Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Ah, I see, the great Brazilean TeX user is here ;-)

Comment: @Christian: Who?! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Hello! That is absolutely perfect for my purposes. Could you please answer the question with that information, so I can accept the answer? Thank you very much! EDIT: I'm getting the following error when trying to load the package: "! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
v
l.17 ...paper,capitulo,titlepage=false]{br-lex} \\
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'." What does this mean?

Comment: @Aloizio: the author submitted an updated version to CTAN. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, I've just uploaded this tiny fix to CTAN. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CTAN has a document class named `lex-br`, written in accordance with the Brazilian Complementary Law 95, which has instructions on how to typeset laws and norms. The class author is my good friend Youssef Cherem. `:)`

The class is avaliable in recent TeX distributions. There's an example available as well in the bundle:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,capitulo,titlepage=false]{br-lex}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    Presidência da República\\
    Casa Civil\\
    Subchefia para Assuntos Jurídicos   
\end{center}

\titulo{Lei Complementar Nº 95,\\ 
       de 26 de fevereiro de 1998}

\descricao{Dispõe sobre a elaboração, a redação, a alteração e a consolidação
das leis, conforme determina o parágrafo único do art. 59 da Constituição
Federal, e estabelece normas para a consolidação dos atos normativos que
menciona}

O PRESIDENTE DA REPÚBLICA Faço saber que o Congresso  Nacional decreta
e eu sanciono a seguinte Lei Complementar:

\chapter{DISPOSIÇÕES PRELIMINARES}
\label{chap:disposicoes}

\artigo A elaboração, a redação, a alteração e a consolidação das leis
obedecerão ao disposto nesta Lei Complementar.

Parágrafo único. As disposições desta Lei Complementar aplicam-se, ainda,
às medidas provisórias e demais atos normativos referidos no art. 59 da 
Constituição Federal, bem como, no que couber, aos decretos e aos demais
atos de regulamentação expedidos por órgãos do Poder Executivo.

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: This lex-br package uses the mwbk package. Is it easy to do an alternative version of lex-br that uses koma script packages?